# Questions about File Guidelines in KDP

Tags: kindle

I don't understand some requirements listed in here: https://kdp.amazon.com/en_US/help/topic/G202145060

Is the native file the file I give to Amazon?
What does embed fonts and images mean?
What are single-page files? Files with only one page?

If this is the wrong place to ask these questions or if there is a duplicate please let me know. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The link you provided is for PRINT books setup at KDP.
This forum is for eBooks (epub and fixed layout ebooks).
So...if your project is for printed books then you might want to repost it over at
[graphic design stackexhange](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/)
If your project is eBooks then someone here should be able to help (if you have any ebook questions).

Here are some minor pointers for printed books using Adobe InDesign software.

**Embedded fonts:**
When the book is created using (for example) InDesign, various fonts and images are used by you in the project. System fonts are operating system fonts that can be used in any book project on your computer (including for exporting to PDF). Software fonts (such as from Adobe) that came with your book design software (or are free at Adobe) can be used commercially (and were paid for by you when you purchased the software).

There are some other free fonts online from font libraries that you can use within your projects without limit, but you will need to read their specs to determine which of those are free to use commercially or if they have a license.

Fonts with the appropriate embedding bits will be auto embedded in your book project. A popup screen may appear when opening your project indicating if fonts are missing [or limited].
To verify if any font problems exist in your project: Acrobat Pro > Tools > print production > preflight > expand > embed fonts = to view fonts and permissions (to see if any did not qualify to be embedded).

**Embedded Images** are linked back to the original image by linking or embedding upon that book page within InDesign. There are two ways to place an image upon a book page (in certain InDesign software) one of which merely links it, while the other option embeds it.

**Adobe PDF Presets settings:**
When that finished book project is exported to a PDF and during your book exporting process it has various click settings that indicate to 'embed' all fonts that were used in the InDesign book project.
There is an option within the Preset PDF settings to make a % subset fonts (this is likely what Amazon KDP is indicating **not** to do).
Images are usually embedded upon PDF export, but some other software may have a click choice option that I am not familiar with.

The page 'spreads' option also exists in the PDF Preset settings (if you choose to use it).
Example of page spreads:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/view-a-two-page-spread-3d58c31a-5269-4a18-915b-2a2c559494a9

**Native file:**
For example, Adobe InDesign (etc) is original native software used to create a book. You do not provide the native file to KDP; they want the exported PDF from it.
That software has various export options (to export to PDF).
The exported PDF is the file you will submit to KDP.

**Page Spreads:**
Most book designers tend to setup their InDesign book pages as side by side two-page spread (to make it easier to see actual page spread as seen in a real book). When the InDesign book project is exported to a PDF, it is automatically changed to single page exported spread (and can be viewed in Adobe Acrobat as each SINGLE page). These settings can be altered in the pre-settings for PDF inside the native InDesign software program.
That KDP help page is merely wanting each book page to be a single page spread in the PDF followed by the next page and so forth all the way through the book (all within one single PDF). The PDF will be scrollable from page to page through the entire book (all within one single exported PDF file).

Note that different software (than InDesign) has uniquely different settings than described above. Hopefully we have described most of the above correctly (though certain software might vary).
You likely can attain a more thorough explanation by posting your question at the other Stackexchange graphic design link mentioned above.

Oh, and if you are doing "Fixed Layout" PDF for Amazon KDP then yes some of that info on that page would apply.